# Facebook authentification with omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, facebook-authentication

I'm encountering an issue with this [tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/bsfitw/ruby-on-rails-4-authentication-with-facebook-and-omniauth) to write a Facebook authentification system.

First, I had an error ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError. I corrected it with [coderhs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619109/rails-activemodelforbiddenattributeserror).

Now when I log in with Facebook it works, but when I log in with annother account, it overwrites the previous user in my table, so I can't have more than one Facebook user connected at the same time and still keep user information about them.

**User.rb**

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid)).first_or_create.tap do |user|
        user.provider ||= auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.name = auth.info.name
        user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
        user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
        user.save!
    end
```

**EDIT**
I noticed first_or_create edit the last query inserted and do not create entry, i added it:

**User.rb**

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
        where(auth.slice(uid: auth.uid)).first_or_create.tap do |user|
            if user.uid == auth.uid
                puts "\nUserModel:_________" + auth.provider + " - " + auth.uid + "\n"
            else
                puts "\nUnknown user        " + auth.uid
            end
            user.provider = auth.provider
            user.uid = auth.uid
            user.name = auth.info.name
            user.email = auth.info.email
            user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
            user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
            user.save
        end
    end
```

When i sign-in with a 2nd account, the else puts is displayed in the console but it edit and not create a new row in the table

**Edit2 [Solution]**

**User.rb**

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
        User.find_or_create_by(uid: auth.uid).tap do |user|
            if user.uid == auth.uid
                puts "\nUserModel:_________" + auth.provider + " - " + auth.uid + "\n"
            else
                puts "\nUnknown user        " + auth.uid
            end
            user.provider = auth.provider
            user.uid = auth.uid
            user.name = auth.info.name
            user.email = auth.info.email
            user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
            user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
            user.save
        end
    end
```

[**Second question solved by Oleksandr Avoyants**]I also want to know how to get the email from the Facebook user. I tried to add

```
user.email = auth.email
```

...but it was too easy to be true.

Comment: Your question about getting the email seems like a distinct question from the issues with supporting multiple users. You may want to create a separate question for that.

Comment: Indeed maybe I should, i didn't know if it was a good thing to create a second post for 3 lines

Comment: It's true sometimes a short question can be labeled "low quality" for its length, but the problem with more than one question in a question is that you get answers which only solve part of your question, as you're seeing. It's not something that's easy to anticipate, so it's an understandable confusion.

Comment: I edited the post. The error come from First_or_create method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [omniauth-facebook README](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#auth-hash) you can get user's email with:

```
auth.info.email
```

NOTE: The precise information available may depend on the permissions which you request.