# ForbiddenAttributesError ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, omniauth

I have this model in Ruby but it throws a `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice("uid", "nickname", "image")).first ||  create_from_omniauth(auth)
end

def self.create_from_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
        user.uid = auth["uid"]
        user.name = auth["info"]["nickname"]
        user.image = auth["info"]["image"]
    end
  end
end
```

when i run this action

```
def auth_callback
  user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
session[:user_id] = user.id
redirect_to root_url, notice: "signed in!"

end
end
```

on ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]

Can you please tell me how to get rid of this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if this [issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3157) is related to this.

Comment: I don't think it's the same issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the `slice` method it no longer available to bypass strong parameters.
Try this code, which tries to be more specific for auth options:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider 
    user.uid      = auth.uid
    user.name     = auth.info.name
    user.save
  end
end
```

You may probably need to use `auth[:provider]` instead of `auth.provider`.
Let me know in the comments if this works for you.
You can also browse [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399414/rails-4-1-5-omniauth-strong-parameters) that helped me out.